# What is the best method to extract several numeric sections for Twitter stats from a longer string?

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and needed to display some Twitter stats on a web page, a Google search not involving OAuth wasn't very successful, I did find a couple of posts here on Stackoveflow that covered a similar problem but I didn't understand the code and the links to the demos involved had expired. So I played around with some different methods until I came up with the following:

```
// Original string broken down to the part I need which is now named as $tweetinfo:
$tweetinfo = getTwitterFollowers('a/c name', 'en');
//$tweetinfo now reads: "Tweets Tweets, current page. 826 Following Following 1,902 Followers Followers 2,177 Likes Likes 473   More"

//Strips down to numbers only 82619022176473
$string = $tweetinfo;  
$number = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string);  

// Print to file
echo file_put_contents("tweets.txt",substr($number, 0, 3)); //outputs 826
echo file_put_contents("followers.txt",substr($number, 7, 4)); //outputs 2176
echo file_put_contents("likes.txt",substr($number, 11, 3)); //outputs 473
```

It works but I am sure there are much better methods that would take in consideration the fact that these numbers will change over time with hundreds becoming thousands but I am not experienced enough to know what to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really directly related to Twitter, but more just a question of how to extract some numbers from a string.

If I was trying to get numbers out of a string like that, I'd start by just removing the commas to simplify the regex, then just `preg_match_all` to find all sequences of digits.

```
$tweetinfo = str_replace(',', '', $tweetinfo);
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $tweetinfo, $numbers);
```

For your example string, `$matches` will be:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "826"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1902"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "2177"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "473"
  }
}
```

You can probably deal with it from there.

---

Side note - I personally haven't worked with the Twitter API, but I assume it would probably have methods for this kind of thing that would be easier than this.

Comment: I want to learn from this but I must be doing something wrong because I can't find anything in that array. Could you please explain in detail exactly how I would print 2177 from that.

Comment: Sure, it would be `echo $numbers[0][2];`. Maybe you missed the additional array level?

Comment: No, that's exactly the way I tried it and the array was coming up as empty then I realised that I had made a typo on the string name. DOH! Thank you Don't Panic it works perfectly, I now have the script running as a cron job and the page will always be up-to-date regardless of the numbers changing from hundreds to thousands, cheers.

Comment: Regarding your side note, The Twitter API would be far better but unfortunatly in 2013 they retired V.1 of their API and now requires that any Twitter app is authenticated first so now it is far more complicated and you have to jump through hoops to get the OAuth Settings. I am a web designer and my client is not technically minded enough to go through this process which as the account owner means he would have to be the one to do it. I have explained as simply as I can, the steps he needs to make and hopefully at some point I'll get the right settings to use in place of my hack.